# phalcon GET routes allowing any other non http method to make successful request to that route

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

I'm using `Phalcon\Mvc\Router` to map the routes and I have a GET route `/api/test` like this,

```
 $router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router(false);
 $router->addGet('/api/test', [
        'module'        => 'api',
        'controller'    => 'test',
        'action'        => 'testapi',
 ]);
```

I'm able to make a GET request to this route and I'm able to get a 200 response, but if I make the method an invalid HTTP method and make a request (as below) it's also givinh me 200 response.

```
curl --location --request NOTHTPPMETHOD 'http://localhost/api/test'
```

I have tried changing `addGet` to `add` and passing the method
I have tried chaining the `via` function in `Phalcon\Mvc\Router` and passig `['GET']`

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behaviour. What your app is missing is to implement the `notFound` method. Add to your router:

```
$router->notFound(
  [
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action'     => 'fourOhFour',
  ]
);
```

Or in a REST API:

```
$app->notFound(
  function () use ($app) {
    $app->response
       ->setStatusCode(404, 'Not found')
       ->setJsonContent([
        'success' => false,
        'msg' => 'Endpoint not found'
      ])
      ->send();
  }
);
```

Another useful method is `error`:

```
$app->error(
  function ($exception) {
    $this->response
      ->setStatusCode(503, 'Server unavailable')
      ->setContent('Error: ' . $exception->getMessage())
      ->send();
  }
);
```

In this way your app can respond with custom messages and http status codes to failed requests.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly, the default route is kicking in. When you create a new instance of `Phalcon\Mvc\Router`, the default constructor argument is set to `true`, which is the equivalent of doing `$router->add('/:controller/:action/:params')`.

What you want to do is to pass the optional parameter as `false`. That is to say, do `$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router(false)`, then it won't add the default route.